# Coercing a character to a numeric in R

Tags: r, coercion

I'm a newbie to R and I've learnt that a character string like "12.5" can be coerced to a numeric using `as.numeric()` function, which gives me the following result.

```
> as.numeric("12.5")
[1] 12.5
```

But when I try following, the result doesn't contain the fractional part.

```
> as.numeric("12.0")
[1] 12
```

is there a way to keep the fractional part in the result...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: There is no fractional part to keep.

Comment: As @MatthewLundberg points out there is no fractional part to keep.  Note that there is a difference between what is stored and what is displayed.  You can get R to show a certain number of digits after the decimal place no matter what but that is a different question.

Comment: Hi Dason, "You can get R to show a certain number of digits after the decimal place no matter what". If you can show me how to do that it would be a great help...

Comment: Take a look at `?sprintf`.  ` sprintf("%.1f", as.numeric("12"))`

Comment: Still a character vector though

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to print whole numbers that way?  If you're worried about how it will appear with other numbers, say in a vector or data frame, not to worry.  If you have at least one decimal number in the vector, the whole number will appear as a decimal as well.

```
> as.numeric(c("12.0", "12.1"))
## [1] 12.0 12.1

> data.frame(x = as.numeric(c("12.0", "12.1")))
##      x
## 1 12.0
## 2 12.1
```

If it's simply for appearance purposes, there are a few functions that can make `12.0` *appear* numeric.  Keep in mind, however that this does not coerce to numeric, even though it looks like it does.

```
> noquote("12.0")
## [1] 12.0

> cat("12.0")
## 12.0
```